# Postgres delete is super slow, how to improve?

Tags: postgresql

My query

```
delete from test.t1 where t2_id = 1;
```

My main table is t1 (includes around 1M rows and need to delete about 100k rows)

```
CREATE TABLE test.t1
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  t2_id bigint,
  ... other fields
  CONSTRAINT pk_t1 PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_t1_t2 FOREIGN KEY (t2_id)
      REFERENCES test.t2 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I have index on t2_id and 3 other indexes on plain string fields.

```
CREATE INDEX t1_t2_idx ON test.t1 USING btree (t2_id);
```

There are multiple (around 50) tables that reference test.t1. I have an index on t1_id for every table that references it.

```
CREATE TABLE test.t7
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  t1_id bigint,
  ... other fields
  CONSTRAINT pk_objekt PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_t7_t1 FOREIGN KEY (t1_id)
      REFERENCES test.t1 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE INDEX t7_t1_idx ON test.t7 USING btree (t1_id);
//No other indexes here
```

Contents of t7 are deleted before t1 and it's super fast compared to removing from t1. Ratio of rows to delete is the same (~10%), but the total number of rows is considerably smaller (around 100K).

I have not been able to reduce the time to reasonable length:

- I've tried removing all index-is (cancelled after 24h-s)
- Kept only t1_t2_idx and t7_t1_idx ... t50_t1_idx indexes (cancelled after 24h-s)
- Kept all indexes (cancelled after 24h-s)

Also vacuum analyze is performed before deletion and there should not be any locks (only active query in db).

I have not tried copying to temp table and truncating t1, but this does not seem reasonable since t1 can grow up to 10M rows from which 1M need to be deleted at some point.

Any ideas how to improve removing?

**EDIT**

Quite sure there are no locks because pg_stat_activity shows only 2 active queries (delete and pg_stat_activity)

```
"Delete on test.t1 (cost=0.43..6713.66 rows=107552 width=6)"
"  ->  Index Scan using t1_t2_idx on test.t1 (cost=0.43..6713.66 rows=107552 width=6)"
"        Output: ctid"
"        Index Cond: (t1.t1_id = 1)"
```

Comment: Are you sure those long running deletes weren't waiting for some lock? Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (verbose)`** (you obviously can't use `analyze` if the query never finishes). [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The CONSTRAINTs are there to ensure cross table consistency. What if you remove all of them? and then do the delete? -This may not be a solution, but just a way to get a sense of the problem. Perhaps adding them later will be a more manageable task.

Comment: And droppring the (50) indexes with the constraints still active is a terrible idea.

Comment: Removing the constraints does not seem like an option since in production  the table is being read from while removing is in process (different rows though)

Comment: I thought I should try deleting in batches so I ran `explain analyze delete from test.t1 where t2_id = x and id < 10` and found that my n-to-n junction tables (6 of them) where missing FK indexes. It spent around 3-4s searching for FKs. 

After adding indexes on junction tables total deletion time came down to 40 minutes. I'll see if I can optimize it more...

**So adding FKs on indexes works, just have to be extra careful to cover all the FKs.**